# How to open file automatically on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

When i open a page with `.exe`, it doesn't open and download it, please help me! (this is my html content):

```
function load(){
    window.location.href = "//somewhere.abc/somefolder/something.exe";
}
```

```js
<body onload="load()">
    <center>
        <iframe data-aa='107686' src='https://ad.a-ads.com/107686?size=990x90' scrolling='no' style='width:990px; height:90px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden' allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0'></iframe>
        <h1>Downloading.......</h1>
        <iframe data-aa='107687' src='https://ad.a-ads.com/107687?size=990x90' scrolling='no' style='width:990px; height:90px; border:0px; padding:0;overflow:hidden' allowtransparency='true' frameborder='0'></iframe>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: you want to run exe? are you getting 404 error?

Comment: Do you want to open the binary file in the browser as a text file or want to automatically run the .exe on the client (which is impossible, fortunately) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can't really execute a `.exe` file automatically in client just like that. That would totally defeat the purpose of "***Security***" of your client's computer, if there has been a way.

Alternatively, you can invoke a file download by using,

```
<iframe id="download_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<script>
function Download() {
    document.getElementById('download_iframe').src = "//somewhere.abc/somefolder/something.exe";
};
Download();
</script>
```

This way, your client ***will be*** asked whether to "Save" or "Run" the file.

Hope this helps. :)